# Comparing Value of one list inside Gigantic Two Dimen list in python, Fastest way?

Tags: python, performance, list, comparison, list-comprehension

I want to compare if value of one list exist in value of other list.They are huge (50k + items, from database).

## EDIT:

I also want to mark the record which is duplicated as duplicate=True and keep them in the table for later refrence.

here how the lists are:

```
n_emails=[db_id,checksum for id,checksum in search_results]
#I want to compare checksum if exist inside same list or other list and retrieve id (db_id , if exist)
#example : n_emails= [[1,'CAFEBABE010'],[2,'bfeafe3df1ds],[3,'deadbeef101'],[5,'CAFEBABE010']] 
#in this case i want to retrive id 1 and 5 coz they are same checksum

for m in n_emails:
    dups=_getdups(n_emails,m[1],m[0])           
    n_dups=[casesdb.duplicates.insert( **dup ) for dup in dups]
    if n_dups:
        print "Dupe Found"
        casesdb(casesdb.email_data.id == m[0]).update(duplicated=True)

def _getdups(old_lst,em_md5,em_id):
    dups=[]
    for old in old_lst:
        if em_md5==old[0] and old[1]!=em_id:
            dups.append(dict(org_id=old[1],md5hash=old[0],dupID=em_id,))
    return dups
```

But it seems too long and in larger list (50k vs 50k records+) It ran for over 5000 seconds and never done , seems never ending loop?
The server i running have 4 GB of ram and 4 cores. Obviously i am doing something wrong.

Please help .. thanks a lot!

## SOLVED:

Dict Index Mapping is way a lot faster! (When mysql table is not indexed, plese note i have not test against indexed table).

Its 20 secs vs 30 miliseconds =  20*1000 / 30 = 666 Times! LOL

Comment: Is there are reason why you would want to do this in code instead of via a database query?

Comment: Do your want to remove the duplicated values? Because there should be more effective ways if you put your final demands.

Comment: What i want to do is to get Duplicated Entries, and build a table holding them, which will be refrenced later. Lets say When user browse a record , he/she will be shown with a list of duplicated entries so he/she can also check them (or skip them). Mysql's distinct will eliminate duplicates right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fastest way is to use a dict like this:

```
n_emails= [[1,'CAFEBABE010'],[2,'bfeafe3df1ds'],[3,'deadbeef101'],[5,'CAFEBABE010']]

d = {}
for id, hash in n_emails:
    if hash not in d:
        d[hash] = [id]
    else:
        d[hash].append(id)

for hash, ids in d:
    if len(ids) > 1:
       print hash, ids
```

this is nearly the algorithm for a hash join

---

```
for hash, count in select hash, count(id) as num from emails group by num having num > 1:
    first = None
    for index, id in enumerate(select id from emails where hash=hash sort by desc id):
        if index == 0:
            first = id
            continue
        update emails set duplicate=first where id=id
```

would be the sql/python solution in this i take the duplicate column and use it to store which message this one is thought to be a duplicate of

the emails table would be at least:

```
create table emails (id, hash, duplicate default null)
```

Comment: this is interesting , i am testing it out.

Comment: Using set() as value of hash might be better?

Comment: possibly but i was assuming that there is only one message with a given id although that message may have the same hash as another

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off looking for duplicates with SQL. For example, see [this page describing how to find duplicates](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/delphi/database/f6.shtml).

Pulling all of those results into Python and processing them is never going to be very fast, but if you must, your best bet is to have a dictionary of checksums to IDs:

```
got_checksums = {}
for id, checksum in emails:
    if checksum in got_checksums:
        print id, got_checksums[checksum]
    else:
        got_checksums[checksum] = id
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing wrong is:

- You can probably get the result directly from the database. It's much faster than Python.
- You are doing linear search for the checksums, which means that each of the 50k entries gets compared to *each* of the other 50k entries ... that is a huge number of comparisons.

What you should do is build an index over the checksums. Make a dict that maps `checksum -> entry`. When you insert the entries check if the checksum exists already, if so the entry is a duplicate.

Or you simply use your database, they love indexing.

Comment: I think you got me , now i am asking why am i doing something hard which can easily done with `select id from emails where MD5Hash='CAFEBABE010' ` .. This is what 2 days of not sleeping got me ..

Comment: Still python needs it role , as want to update those who have duplicated in table boolean field `duplicated` .

Comment: @V3ss0n: That sql is only better **if there is a index** over the `MD5Hash` column. You can actually write a single sql query that fetches all the duplicates at once and marks them.

Comment: There is no index and yes , i had already got ID related to MD5Hash during record insertion , so i choose to use dict. And you way , its Order of Magnitude faster! I will post the results.

Answer (score 1):

Finally thanks to all answers I found that dict mapping is insanely fast! Way a lot faster than SQL queries.

Here is my SQL query test (it will seem awkward, but it is syntax of Web2pyDAL's queries).

I tested both for 3500 records and only dict mapping against over 250000 records.

```
print "de_duping started at %s" % str( datetime.datetime.now() )

dupe_n = 0
l_dupe_n = 0
for em_hash in n_emails:
    dup_ids=casesdb(casesdb.email_data.MD5Hash==em_hash[1]).select(casesdb.email_data.id)
    if dup_ids>1:
        dupe_n+=1

print "Email Dupes %s" % (dupe_n)
print "Local de_duping ended at %s" % str( datetime.datetime.now() )
```

Resullts in:

```
de_duping started at 2010-12-02 03:39:24.610888
Email Dupes 3067
Local de_duping ended at 2010-12-02 03:39:52.669849
```

about 28 secs
heres the dict based indexing map based on Dan D

```
    print "de_duping started at %s" % str( datetime.datetime.now() )
    for id, hash in em_hash:

            if hash not in dedupe_emails:

                dedupe_emails[hash] = [id]
            else:

                dedupe_emails[hash].append( id )
                dupe_n += 1
                casesdb( casesdb.email_data.id == id ).update( duplicated = True )

    print "Email Dupes %s" % (dupe_n)
    print "Local de_duping ended at %s" % str( datetime.datetime.now() )
```

results in :

```
de_duping started at 2010-12-02 03:41:21.505235
Email Dupes 2591 # this is accurate as selecting from database regards first match as duplicate too
Local de_duping ended at 2010-12-02 03:41:21.531899
```

only what? 30 ms!

and lets see what it done against de-duping 250k records!

```
de_duping at 2010-12-02 03:44:20.120880
Email Dupes 93567 
Local de_duping ended at 2010-12-02 03:45:12.612449
```

Less Than a  min!!

Thanks to all answers , i would like to select all those who pointed me correct way , but Dan D give me most detailed answer! Thanks Dan!